# How to get first character occurrence in text their keeping original order?

Tags: c#, string, linq

I try to get first character occurrence in text keeping their original order. I try to use LINQ but I'm very new in this, so something is wrong, and I have bad result.

For example I write: "languages", so the result would l-0, a-1, n-2, g-3, u-4, e-7, s-8 (digit mean index of occurrence). But my code gives: l-0, a-1, n-2, g-3, u-4, e-**5**, s-**6**.

So index number is 0,1,2,3,4,5 no matter what. That's my code:

```
char[] result = text.ToLower()
    .Where(char.IsLetter)
    .GroupBy(x => x)
    .Select(g => g.Key).ToArray();

for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
{
    listView1.Items.Add(result[i].ToString());
    listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(i.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Please don't add "C#." to the subject, since you've already got it in the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `Regex`:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

var q = from ch in text.Distinct()
        select Regex.Match(text, ch.ToString());
foreach (var item in q)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}-{1}", item.Value, item.Index);
}
```

And a non-regex alternative:

```
var q = from ch in text.Distinct()
        select new { Value = ch, Index = text.IndexOf(ch) };
```

Comment: Your approach will handily find the characters, but it will need to ignore duplicate characters. Perhaps loop over `Regex.Matches` while updating/checking a `Dictionary` or `HashSet`.

Comment: Thanx, but it doesn't need ignore duplicates, just first occurrences all characters in text.

Comment: Updated my answer, I believe it answers your question now :)

Comment: I'm even afraid to say something, b/c it seems to me, that it works! So thanx u a lot, I really help me. But can I ask the one question, How to use it in function? What to return?

Answer (score 3):

Using LINQ I believe you're trying to accomplish the following:

```
string input = "languages";
var query = input.Select((c, i) => new { Char = c, Index = i })
                 .Where(o => Char.IsLetter(o.Char))
                 .GroupBy(o => o.Char)
                 .Select(g => g.First());

foreach (var item in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", item.Char, item.Index);
}
```

You can use the overloaded `Select` method to grab the index of each character. With the original indices captured, you're free to further manipulate the results. Now you can filter for characters only, group them by character and, finally, take the `First()` item from each group.

Comment: Thanx a lot. But I can't understand how can I use it. query.First? But how to put it into loop?

Comment: @Ahmad I didn't know about the "builtin" index in LINQ's select. +1 to your answer (mine tried unnecessarily to recreate the index with a "Zip")

Comment: Answer is good, but I need to keep order how it is in source text, for example: string = "dcba", result would - d-0, c-1, b-2, a-3.

Comment: @Daria that is what the first part of the query accomplishes, specifically with `input.Select((c, i) => new { Char = c, Index = i })
`. With just that part you have access to each character and its index. I suggest you comment out the rest of the query and use only this line, `foreach` over the results and print them out to understand it as I've shown above, then add more LINQ as needed till you build up to the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any specific reason you wanted to use LINQ here?

You are not preserving the position of the first occurence in the LINQ query. What you get is a simply a list of all characters.

Looping through the characters in a string and using a `Dictionary<char,int>` to store the position of the first occurrence would get your task done.

```
 public static Dictionary<char, int> FirstOccurence(string str)
    {
        char[] strArr = str.ToCharArray();
        Dictionary<char, int> firstOccur = new Dictionary<char, int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < strArr.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!firstOccur.ContainsKey(strArr[i]))
            {
                firstOccur[strArr[i]] = i;
            }
        }
        return firstOccur;
    }
```

Comment: So... I just was sure that LINQ is very useful when u're working with strings or characters. I'ts not nesessity. So thank you so much for your answer it looks helpfull, so I'll try to use it.

Comment: @Daria It's definitely powerful and I just started learning it. But for trivial tasks I feel its a overkill.

Comment: Really thank you for the answer and advices. I hope your answer would help me. Oops, but the func is void? So how to use it?

Comment: Oh, there is KeyNotFoundExaption in line if(...).

Comment: @Daria, @Ravi, you'll need to use the [Dictionary.TryGetValue method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx) to check if the key exists in order to avoid the `KeyNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
string text="languages";
var ints = Enumerable.Range(0,text.Length); 

var firstOccurrences = 
   from couple in text.Zip(ints, (a,b) => new{character=a, index=b})
   where char.IsLetter(couple.character)
   group couple by couple.character into cn
   select new {ch=cn.Key, minindex=cn.Min(c => c.index)};

   foreach(var f in firstOccurrences)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("char:{0} - first occurs: {1}",f.ch,f.minindex);
    }
```